# Preserve table info when converting AutoCAD .DWG to MapInfo .TAB

Tags: mapinfo, autocad, dwg, tab, autocad-map

I've been using Universal Translator to convert some .DWG files into .TAB.
I would like to know if there is there is a way to preserve the data in the AutoCAD file's table when converting to .TAB?
Currently the tables are empty after the conversion:

[image]

Comment: What tabular data do think in AutoCAD?

Comment: @Zoltan, I'm not sure. Someone asked me to "preserve the original tabular data". I don't deal with AutoCAD at all except for converting objects into MapInfo for infrastructure. Is there no data behind AutoCAD files like there is being MapInfo objects?

Comment: AFAIK Universal Translator won't import any attribute data from AutoCAD. Some GIS software import  from DWG/DXF layer, color, line width, ... (display attributes) for example ArcGIS.

Comment: @Zoltan, I had someone show me that through Universal Translator, inc hanging some of the parameters, he was able to populate the objects table with some of the information, but I'm not sure what they selected within the parameters. Do you know of this?

Comment: @KDawk, sorry I used to use an older version of UT, where these options were not available.

Comment: @Zoltan, no worries. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a little digging, the setting in Universal Translator that I needed to populate the table with the information was through Parameters --> Group Entities By --> Attribute Schema, which then allowed the TAB to import information including each polygons name.

[image]